# How can I capture data send to a webserver/website?

Tags: http

What is an easy way to capture data send to a webserver?

I want to get the code, which gets send when I give someone reputation on a forum...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Fiddler. It acts as a system-wide proxy and captures all http requests and provides a way to inspect them.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is sent using a browser.
You can monitor the traffic using Firebug in firefox or Developer Console in Chrome.